# How do i add desciption when using Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

What is the proper way to add a description to an IP address that is added with this command.

```
Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress -GroupName 'Postgres GIS' -ProfileName default -IpPermission @{IpProtocol='tcp'; FromPort='5432'; ToPort='5432'; IpRanges="$($ip.CidrIP)";}
```

When I go to  AWS security group and look at inbound tab I see the IP address is added but description is blank.  I want to fill this in.  How?

Do I have to try something else like this command

Update-

EC2SecurityGroupRuleIngressDescription to change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have expected you to be able to use `Description="xyz"` in the IpPermission list but, as you've confimed, it's not supported. It looks like this may be missing from the [Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress cmdlet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=EC2/TEC2IpPermission.html&tocid=Amazon_EC2_Model_IpPermission) but you can set the description as follows (from [example 6](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress.html)):

```
PS C:\> $IpRange = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.EC2.Model.IpRange
PS C:\> $IpRange.CidrIp = "5.5.5.5/32"
PS C:\> $IpRange.Description = "SSH from Office"
PS C:\> $IpPermission = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.IpPermission
PS C:\> $IpPermission.IpProtocol = "tcp"
PS C:\> $IpPermission.ToPort = 22
PS C:\> $IpPermission.FromPort = 22
PS C:\> $IpPermission.Ipv4Ranges = $IpRange
PS C:\> Grant-EC2SecurityGroupIngress -GroupId sg-1234abcd -IpPermission $IpPermission
```

Comment: Simply adding description to ippermission didn't work, however example 6 did work. I had read that page before but missed that example.  THanks!

Comment: Strange. I think it should be supported, but glad you worked around it. Have updated my answer.